# Apache Ignite - In case of a SQL Select, is there any order by which Apache Ignite return the results?

Tags: sql, ignite

I would like to know if there is any ordering done by Apache Ignite before returning a result for a select sql.
For example:

```
Collection<List<?>> result = igniteCache.query(new SqlFieldsQuery("SELECT * FROM CACHE_TABLE_1 p1").getAll();
```

Is there any specific order the SELECT returns the results?

Comment: If you need order, you should use ORDER BY

Answer (score 0):

The order is not defined and you should never depend on it.